# How to add minutes column to Instant value in jOOQ

Tags: jooq

Given a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE demo (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    offset_minutes INTEGER NOT NULL,
    scheduled_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

I want to update `scheduled_time` to an application-supplied time plus `offset_minutes`. In plain SQL on PostgreSQL, it'd look something like

```sql
UPDATE demo
SET scheduled_time =
    timestamp with time zone '2022-09-12T01:23:45Z' +
        offset_minutes * interval '1 minute'
WHERE id = 12345;
```

What's the best way to express this in jOOQ in a database-engine-independent way?

This is the reverse of the usual way people want to add minutes to a time value, which is well-covered by other SO questions: in my case, the `Instant` is supplied by the code and the number of minutes is in a database column, not the other way around.

The best I've been able to come up with is to do a floating-point calculation on the number of minutes, since we can add days to `Instant`s:

```java
dslContext.update(DEMO)
    .set(DEMO.SCHEDULED_TIME,
        DSL.instant(instant).add(DEMO.OFFSET_MINUTES.div(24.0 * 60.0)))
    .where(DEMO.ID.eq(id))
    .execute();
```

On PostgreSQL, jOOQ ends up generating a SQL expression for the value of the `SET` clause:

```sql
(timestamp with time zone '2022-09-12 01:23:45+00:00' +
    ("public"."demo"."offset_minutes" / 1.44E3) * interval '1 day')
```

The fact that jOOQ is generating `interval '1 day'` makes me hopeful that there's a way to tell it to change `day` to `minute` and avoid the floating-point calculation. I'm never nuts about doing floating-point calculations on discrete quantities if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Pending feature requests

**Fixing your immediate problem**

There's a pending feature request [#6723](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6723) to add support for `DSL::offsetDateTimeAdd`, which would allow for adding intervals to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data types.

It still wouldn't work for `Instant` data types, where we'd need yet another "overload" for all the possible date time arithmetic variants.

Both of these would produce a lot of new methods in an already crowded `DSL` class, without really adding much new functionality, given they're doing something similar to the existing `timestampAdd()` or `localDateTimeAdd()` functions, just offering the same thing for new types.

**A more strategic, thorough change**

There's a big change [#11088](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11088) suggested on the long term roadmap, which would allow for more cleanly separating the usual two types `T` and `U` involved with a `Field`:

- `T` being the "JDBC type", i.e. the type the database understands (e.g. `OffsetDateTime`)
- `U` being the "user type", i.e. the type you want to see in your code (e.g. `Instant`)

This way, there would be a single method accepting `T = OffsetDateTime` and any arbitrary `U` type (e.g. `Instant`).

#### Workaround for you right now

While the above tasks take time to get right, you can always use the usual escape hatch and use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). E.g.

```java
DSL.field("({0} + {1} * interval '1 minute')", 
    SQLDataType.INSTANT,
    DSL.instant(instant), 
    DEMO.OFFSET_MINUTES
);
```

You can extract the hard-coded arguments (`DSL.instant(instant)` and `DEMO.OFFSET_MINUTES`) and make a reusable function for the above, and thus create a mini library for the missing functionality in jOOQ.