# jOOQ doesn't log the SQL queries it executes, despite enabling DEBUG logging

Tags: java, jooq

My application uses Logback and I've enabled `DEBUG` logging for `org.jooq` in my Logback configuration. Despite this, jOOQ doesn't log the SQL queries (as it ought to). What can be causing this?

Comment: Can you share the jOOQ part of your logback configuration? You may also have a look at those 2: https://blog.jooq.org/debug-logging-sql-with-jooq/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561317/how-can-we-profile-jooq-statements-for-speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at this a bit more (it was a problem I ran into [last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72743011/how-to-get-the-jooq-query-text-using-aspectj-without-changing-the-query-method-i/72743563?noredirect=1#comment134933890_72743563)), and it turned out I was wrong. jOOQ *did* indeed log the queries, using the `o.j.t.L.o.j.t.LoggerListener`. The problem was just this:

- I was running different queries on multiple threads.
- Other queries were being logged *after* this query.
- This particular query returned 21 million records, leading to the following:

  ```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  Dumping heap to /tmp/java_pid104782.hprof ...

  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the  UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)"

  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "I/O dispatcher 14"
  Heap dump file created [6088668813 bytes in 48.331 secs]

  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "req-rsp-timeout-task"

  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "I/O dispatcher 5"

  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "lettuce-eventExecutorLoop-1-3"

  Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "I/O dispatcher 11"
  ```
- Because of the above, the `Fetched result` and `Fetched row(s)` messages were never logged. And in general, it was hard to understand that it was *that* specific query that failed, because it wasn't the "last" query to be logged, so to speak (because of the queries from the other threads).

What I did to mitigate this was to add an `onRenderEnd` handler for the particular query that was failing (I stepped through the code with the debugger to roughly see which jOOQ query this was). Using this, I was able to pin-point the logging for my particular query more easily.

Posting all these details in the help that it might help others and/or my future self.

```
diff --git a/path/to/MyClass.java b/path/to/MyClass.java
index 92beaa9a91..fcddf9c134 100644
--- a/path/to/MyClass.java
+++ b/path/to/MyClass.java
@@ -30,6 +30,7 @@ import java.util.stream.Stream;
 
 import org.jooq.DSLContext;
 import org.jooq.DatePart;
+import org.jooq.ExecuteListener;
 import org.jooq.Field;
 import org.jooq.Name;
 import org.jooq.Record1;
@@ -417,6 +418,10 @@ public class MyClass {
             // arithmetics on `Field<Instant>` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71508599
             Field<Instant> upperRelatedLimit = field( "(" + seriesTimeFieldName.first() + " + INTERVAL '1 hour')", Instant.class );
 
+            create.configuration().set( ExecuteListener.onRenderEnd( ctx -> {
+                System.out.println( ctx.sql() );
+            } ) );
+
             try ( Stream<AssignedDeviceConnectionState> connectionStates = auditDsl.select(
                     field( "series." + seriesTimeFieldName.first(), Instant.class ).as( "time" ),
                     field( "d.id", Integer.class ).as( "device_id" ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean logging with the [`org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/LoggerListener.html), which by default `DEBUG` logs all your queries and their results.

There's a flag to turn that off completely. It's enabled by default. You may have turned it off with [`Settings.executeLogging`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-execute-logging/).

Another reason may be that jOOQ's `org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger` tries to classload `org.slf4j.Logger` and logs through that if available, falling back to `java.util.logging` otherwise. Do check that you make slf4j available to jOOQ on the classpath or modulepath, and that you have it backed by logback.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I found out why I didn't find the logging for the query in question in my case, posted all the details here now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76570263/227779. (I was wrong in my previous message - it _was_ logged in fact, but I might have missed it when looking at the logs)

Comment: @PerLundberg: Great to hear you've found the issue. Thanks for documenting your solution here.

Comment: Sure, np. Do you mind if I mark my own answer as the "accepted" one, or do you prefer to get the credit for this? Your answer is obviously also good, but technically this wasn't a problem with the `Settings.executeLogging` but rather that I couldn't see the forest for all the trees... ;)

Comment: @PerLundberg: I don't care so much about "internet points" as I care about helping folks :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good attitude. I gave you some "internet points" now anyway. :D